# Python trace unable to find module

Tags: python, trace

I run my python code using a bash script containing:

```
python3 -m  baselines.run --alg=... --env=...  --num_timesteps=...
```

This runs fine. I want to trace code execution so I am trying [trace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html).

When I run:

```
python3 -m trace --trace baselines.run --alg=... --env=... --num_timesteps=...
```

I get the error:

> Cannot run file 'baselines.run' because: [Errno 2] No such file or
>   directory: 'baselines.run'

I would like to keep using the `-m` flag  as relative imports will work correctly with baselines.run as the starting point.

Any suggestions on why this is occuring?

Comment: ```python3 -m trace --trace -m baselines.run --alg=... --env=... --num_timesteps=...```
You can try to add -m before baselines.run

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately this still gives the same error. I think `trace` does not allow running of modules using the `-m` flag.